# Forbidden para qualquer htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, apache

Estou usando o servidor portátil Uniform Server, já descomentei a linha para ativar o mod_rewrite do apache, porém estou recebendo o error **403 forbidden** para qualquer arquivo .htaccess que usar, este primeiro é do CodeIgniter:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Este segundo de outra aplicação:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

OBS: também já substitui `AllowOverride None`por `AllowOverride All`

Por que isso ocorre?

Comment: Verificou usuário e permissões ?

Comment: Não sabia que precisava fazer isso no windows, até porque eu só copiei de outra pasta, que no caso é do xampp, e já estava funcionando.

Comment: Foi um chute! Por isso apenas comentei. Devido ao retorno 403 (proibido o acesso). No caso resolveu? Se não resolveu verifique se o seu arquivo .htaccess está corretamente salvo em ASCII, qualquer carácter adicional pode apresentar esse erro. Apague o arquivo e crie um vazio e force o tipo para ASCII,  e vê se  o servidor roda, depois vá adicionando linha a linha para entender aonde está o problema.

Comment: Coloque um ficheiro `index.php` com um `echo "hello world"` e remova o `.htaccess`. Veja se o status 403 é devolvido na mesma. Se sim, o problema não é do `.htaccess`. Podes postar o ficheiro VirtualHost?